# Building services for Gitlab

Tags: github, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

How to create my own **service** and add it into gitlab? Services like **jira**, **jenkins** are present under integrations in Gitlab. How can I create a service to add it under gitlab Integrations and make it useful for every one's use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "[Project services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/project_services.html)", and it has a ["contribution" section](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/project_services.html#contributing-to-project-services).

It is based on  [`gitlab-org/gitlab-foss`, folder `app/models/project_services`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/tree/master/app/models/project_services), where you can add your own service.

Comment: It means I can even make comment on merge requests in gitlab from that external service right? @VonC

Comment: @DINOLINYPJOB Yes, since it is part of the GitLab open source project.

Comment: Thanks a lot @VonC